# Large image in email moved outside of div

Tags: python, html, css, macos, html-email

#### Problem

I have a weird bug with Mac's Mail Application displaying images in a email sent with Python.

The HTML-formatted email I receive looks like in the picture below. As you can see the second blue picture (size 1048x1048) respects the `float: left;` and is displayed properly while the first one (size 1047x1047) is moved oddly outside the enclosing `div`.

[image]

#### Creating the Email

The code for sending the email (with Gmail) is:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.header import Header
from email.message import EmailMessage
import os


def send_email(receiver, subject, content, attachments=None):
    if attachments is None:
        attachments = []
    if isinstance(receiver, str):
        receiver = [receiver]

    # Credentials
    sender = '...'
    username = '...'
    password = '...'

    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = 'Me <{}>'.format(sender)
    #msg['To'] = target

    msg.set_content(content)

    msg.add_alternative(content, subtype='html')

    for png_cid in attachments:
        full_path_to_png = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(
            os.path.dirname(__file__), attachments[png_cid]
        ))
        with open(full_path_to_png, 'rb') as png_file:
            file_contents = png_file.read()
            msg.get_payload()[1].add_related(file_contents, 'image', 'png', cid=png_cid)

    # The actual mail sent (Gmail SMTP)
    with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587') as server:
        server.starttls()
        server.login(username, password)
        for rec in receiver:
            msg['To'] = rec
            server.sendmail(msg['From'], rec, msg.as_string())



text = """
    <!doctype html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" dir="ltr">
        <head>
            <title>Mail Sitzreservation</title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


            <style type="text/css">
                body{
                    font:14px/20px  'Open Sans', 'Verdana', sans-serif;
                    margin:0;
                    padding:75px 0 0 0;
                    text-align: left;
                    -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;       
                } 
                .ticket {
                    border: 3px solid #ddd;
                    border-radius: 30px;
                    overflow: auto;
                    width: 600px;
                    margin-bottom: 30px;
                    padding: 5px;
                    position: relative;
                    min-height: 150pt;
                }

                .ticket img {
                    float: left;
                    width: 200px;
                    height: 200px;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p>Test</p>

                <center>
                    <div class="ticket">
                        <img src="cid:qrcode_0" width="200" height="200" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="ticket">
                        <img src="cid:qrcode_1" width="200" height="200" />
                    </div>

                </center>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
"""

send_email('me@nowhere.com',
           'Bug-Test', text,
           attachments={'qrcode_0': 'qr_1048.png',
                        'qrcode_1': 'qr_1047.png'})
```

#### Guess

It seems to depend on the file size. It works for images smaller that 1047 pixels but fails from 1048 pixels on.

Is that some kind of internal CSS that Mac's Mail applies? If so, how would I find out, and more importantly, how would I overwrite it?

#### Edit: Email Raw Source

And this is the raw source of the receiced email. I adapted it according to the comment so that it tests out the problem with both `div` or `table`.

```
Return-Path: <...@me.com>
Received: from mail-ed1-f46.google.com ([209.85.208.46]) by mx-ha.gmx.net
 (mxgmx011 [212.227.15.9]) with ESMTPS (Nemesis) id 0MLz3s-1hecv003bQ-007ixz
 for <...@me.com>; Tue, 25 Jun 2019 10:56:10 +0200
Received: by mail-ed1-f46.google.com with SMTP id a14so25961125edv.12
        for <...@me.com>; Tue, 25 Jun 2019 01:56:09 -0700 (PDT)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=gmail.com; s=20161025;
        h=message-id:date:subject:from:mime-version:to;
        bh=Q81uSirS6vgSowxeL9+vx8suDLPGjrIGip4maO4YGdc=;
        b=WDA...dGm
         T+LA==
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=1e100.net; s=20161025;
        h=x-gm-message-state:message-id:date:subject:from:mime-version:to;
        bh=Q81uSirS6vgSowxeL9+vx8suDLPGjrIGip4maO4YGdc=;
        b=aOjG...yt0
         34qA==
X-Gm-Message-State: APjAAAWTlBfGZFL2cUCm9ZhnnYbcpSvKIOPc8heLIaDJPKM+b+0f1wbi
    J2PJWKqq+67llPfIL07is8P7KflU
X-Google-Smtp-Source: APXv...43g==
X-Received: by 2002:a50:b839:: with SMTP id j54mr138783731ede.155.1561452969415;
        Tue, 25 Jun 2019 01:56:09 -0700 (PDT)
Received: from me.home ([2a02:1205:c6ab:8d40:c1a:df46:4e0d:4072])
        by smtp.gmail.com with ESMTPSA id z16sm2300184eji.31.2019.06.25.01.56.05
        for <...@me.com>
        (version=TLS1_3 cipher=AEAD-AES256-GCM-SHA384 bits=256/256);
        Tue, 25 Jun 2019 01:56:08 -0700 (PDT)
Message-ID: <5d11e1a8.1c69fb81.72764.a642@mx.google.com>
Date: Tue, 25 Jun 2019 01:56:08 -0700 (PDT)
Subject: Bug-Test
From: Me <...@me.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="===============1246061451293108858=="
To: ...@me.com
Envelope-To: <...@me.com>
X-GMX-Antispam: 0 (Mail was not recognized as spam); Detail=V3;
X-Spam-Flag: NO
X-UI-Filterresults: notjunk:1;V03:K0:VA+1C0Bdx4s=:1cFy...a3X+6

--===============1246061451293108858==
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


    <!doctype html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" dir="ltr">
        <head>
            <title>Mail Sitzreservation</title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


            <style type="text/css">
                body{
                    font:14px/20px  'Open Sans', 'Verdana', sans-serif;
                    margin:0;
                    padding:75px 0 0 0;
                    text-align: left;
                    -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;       
                } 
                .ticket {
                    border: 3px solid #ddd;
                    border-radius: 30px;
                    overflow-y: visible;
                    overflow-x: auto;
                    width: 600px;
                    margin-bottom: 30px;
                    padding: 5px;
                    position: relative;
                    min-height: 150pt;
                }

                .ticket img {
                    float: left !important;
                    width: 200px;
                    height: 200px;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p>Test</p>

                <center>
                    <table class="ticket"><tr><td>
                        <img src="cid:qrcode_0" width="200" height="200" />
                    </td></tr></table>
                    <table class="ticket"><tr><td>
                        <img src="cid:qrcode_1" width="200" height="200" />
                    </td></tr></table>

                    <div class="ticket">
                        <img src="cid:qrcode_0" width="200" height="200" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="ticket">
                        <img src="cid:qrcode_1" width="200" height="200" />
                    </div>

                </center>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>

--===============1246061451293108858==
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related;
 boundary="===============4631778948648796069=="

--===============4631778948648796069==
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


    <!doctype html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" dir="ltr">
        <head>
            <title>Mail Sitzreservation</title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


            <style type="text/css">
                body{
                    font:14px/20px  'Open Sans', 'Verdana', sans-serif;
                    margin:0;
                    padding:75px 0 0 0;
                    text-align: left;
                    -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;       
                } 
                .ticket {
                    border: 3px solid #ddd;
                    border-radius: 30px;
                    overflow-y: visible;
                    overflow-x: auto;
                    width: 600px;
                    margin-bottom: 30px;
                    padding: 5px;
                    position: relative;
                    min-height: 150pt;
                }

                .ticket img {
                    float: left !important;
                    width: 200px;
                    height: 200px;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p>Test</p>

                <center>
                    <table class="ticket"><tr><td>
                        <img src="cid:qrcode_0" width="200" height="200" />
                    </td></tr></table>
                    <table class="ticket"><tr><td>
                        <img src="cid:qrcode_1" width="200" height="200" />
                    </td></tr></table>

                    <div class="ticket">
                        <img src="cid:qrcode_0" width="200" height="200" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="ticket">
                        <img src="cid:qrcode_1" width="200" height="200" />
                    </div>

                </center>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>

--===============4631778948648796069==
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: qrcode_0
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Disposition: inline

iVBOR...Jggg==

--===============4631778948648796069==
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: qrcode_1
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Disposition: inline

iVBOR...RK5CYII=

--===============4631778948648796069==--

--===============1246061451293108858==--
```

Comment: Try using table `div`'s dont have universal support on email clients.

Comment: Thx, didn't know that. Didn't help though...

Comment: Now the thing happens between 1048 and 1049 pixels, for both `table` and `div`.

Comment: Add in the generated HTML (after you received the email), maybe it has some clues